# What is the best position for Settings in bottom navigation view activity?

Tags: material-design, android

According to [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/settings.html#settings-placement), there are two main places for Settings in an Android application:

1. Navigation Drawer (if present)
2. Upper right corner of the toolbar

Now my problem is that I have a bottom navigation view without any upper toolbar. Since this seems to be a big hole in Material design guidelines, I'm asking in this case what should be the correct place for Settings?

Answer (score 2):

You need to inscribe the 'settings' in the ellipsis **more button** in the [Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#) bar. Directly giving the settings button on the bottom navigation bar also would work, if you have much space in the same.
[image: more button]

Comment: So if I've instead of "More" button, a "Profile" button, it could be considered correct to create inside them a link or a button to settings? FYI the settings are mostly about personal behaviour of push notification and about general info of the app (terms and conditions, version number etc)

Comment: Inside settings, if it was only personal items to be shown, then of course you could have included it inside the settings. But here, as you have general app info, i would not advise including it inside the profile -> settings. Rather More -> 1. Profile 2. Settings would be apt.